# I am having this problem in while downloading Android Studio

Tags: android

i am having this error while i try to download Android Studio..

```
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.6.5)".
Warning: Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v1.RemotePackage@862c48c8" (emulator) should be installed in 
"D:\Program Files\ANDROIDSTUDIOSDK\emulator" but 
it already exists.
Installing in "D:\Program Files\ANDROIDSTUDIOSDK\emulator-2" instead.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-7324830.zip
```

Please help me i am new in Android Studio so please..

Answer (score 1):

you have that file already in that particular path.. try to clear that file in below path D:\Program Files\ANDROIDSTUDIOSDK\emulator-2" and clear all caches then try again..

Hope it will work.. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

As [Nihthiya Althaf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67825582/6543967) answered, you can try to clear the emulator folder, but I think you have to clear the `D:\Program Files\ANDROIDSTUDIOSDK\emulator` folder, and remove the `D:\Program Files\ANDROIDSTUDIOSDK\emulator-2` folder. Or just delete both of them.